# How to find which user permissions are necessary to access a page

Tags: users

I created a custom content type, which has a custom block on it.
When accessing that page, i get an "Access denied" error.

I have no idea which permissions is throwing this.

Does anyone have an idea of how to find the missing permission?

Thanks!

Comment: What access control modules do you have enabled?

Comment: Which is page name/url that you got the "Access Denied" message. Did you create a view(page) for your custom content type or Did you access the node of your custom content type?

Comment: @Triskelion : Hmm, not sure about that. The "default" one of Drupal I'm guessing.

Comment: @StoneVo : i created a page "online-payment" of my custom Content Type, and on it, there is a block that includes an iframe to a distant payment form. Now i'm trying to access this page